# bash/awk/sed/.. concatenate lines that share entries, and the other way around

Tags: bash, awk, concatenation

i would like to know how to concatenate the lines of a file (with multiple columns and rows, >100mb files) for lines that share the same entries in column 1. And also how to unconcatenate a file that has been concatenated in this way.

example:

from file.txt:

```
a 3494 3929 asd 12 fdfdf
b 2323 2390 kjk 32 kjkjk
b 1323 2390 kjk 32 kjkjk
c 2399 9009 dfd 90 sasd
c 9090 1212 jkk 01 kjkk
c 0900 2311 gfg 09 dkjs
d 0909 2322 kjk 98 dskk
d 0909 0903 kjk 98 dskk
d 0909 2422 fdd 98 cvcv
```

to, concatenatedfile.txt

```
a 3494 3929 asd 12 fdfdf
b 2323 2390 kjk 32 kjkjk b 1323 2390 kjk 32 kjkjk
c 2399 9009 dfd 90 sasd c 9090 1212 jkk 01 kjkk c 0900 2311 gfg 09 dkjs
d 0909 2322 kjk 98 dskk d 0909 0903 kjk 98 dskk d 0909 2422 fdd 98 cvcv
```

and the other way around, so: from concatenatedfile.txt -> file.txt

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Will lines with the same column 1 always be next to each other, as in your example, or will they be shuffled?

Comment: in my files they are next to each other, but i guess sorting them is easy?

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this (requires > 100MO RAM):

```
awk '
    {for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) arr[$1]=arr[$1]" "$i}
    END{for (a in arr) print a, arr[a]}
' file.txt
```

### OUTPUT

```
a  3494 3929 asd 12 fdfdf
b  2323 2390 kjk 32 kjkjk 1323 2390 kjk 32 kjkjk
c  2399 9009 dfd 90 sasd 9090 1212 jkk 01 kjkk 0900 2311 gfg 09 dkjs
d  0909 2322 kjk 98 dskk 0909 0903 kjk 98 dskk 0909 2422 fdd 98 cvcv
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative without arrays if field 1 is in consecutive order, try:

```
awk 'END{print RS} p!=$1{if(p)print RS; p=$1}1' ORS= file
```

For the reverse try something like:

```
awk '{for(i=2; i<=NF; i+=1) if( $i==$1 ) $i=RS $i}1' file
```

But that would fail if one of the other fields could have the same value as first field of the reconstructed records, in which case you would need extra checks.

Answer (score 0):

Deconcatenating is fairly simple in `awk`:

```
awk 'NF % 6 != 0 { print "Garbage: ", $0 }
     NF % 6 == 0 { for (i = 1; i < NF; i += 6)
                   {
                       pad = ""
                       for (j = i; j < i+6; j++)
                       {
                           printf "%s%s", pad, $j
                           pad = " "
                       }
                       print ""
                   }
                 }'
```

And here's my concatenation solution. It assumes that the values in column 1 are grouped together.  It won't actually care if they aren't grouped; it will just generate extra lines that it would not have done had the data been grouped.

```
awk 'NF % 6 != 0 { printf "\nGarbage: %s\n", $0 }
     NF % 6 == 0 { if ($1 != old && NR > 1) print ""
                   if ($1 != old) printf "%s", $0
                   else           printf " %s", $0
                   old = $1
                 }
     END         { print "" }'
```

You can leave out the garbage handling if you like — silently ignoring data that doesn't match.